# What is the algorithmic latency of STFT processing?

Tags: fft, audio, window-functions, stft

I was reading this [paper](http://www.cs.tut.fi/sgn/arg/music/tuomasv/barker_icassp2015.pdf), and in section 3 I got a bit confused. It claims that the algorithmic latency is equal to synthesis frame length. If the overlap between two consecutive frames is 50%, the algorithmic latency should be the half of the window size. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: it is not about the latency of STFT.

Comment: @jojek can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The delay is independent of the overlap because you have to wait for a complete block to be filled with new input data before you can do the [transformation$\rightarrow$processing$\rightarrow$inverse transformation] and output a new block of output data which consists - in the case of overlap-add - of the sum of the first samples of the current block and the last samples of the previous last block. (Compare this [figure from the Wikipedia page on the overlap-add algorithm](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Depiction_of_overlap-add_algorithm.png).)